# how to convert one string row into many columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with shape (30420279, 1). some rows contain simple values like size = 100, others include complex values like in the following snipping: 
[image]

other rows contain also other combination of values like the following snipping 
[image]

as we can see now, the rows are like dictionary formate {key = value}. what I wanted to do is to extend the data frame shape from one column (30420279, 1) up to many columns depending on the keys that we have like in the snipping (size, async, batchFrequency..).

Comment: just a heads up - I'm not considering answering because I checked your post history and I see multiple previous questions where someone solved your problem but you didn't vote up or accept their answer. If someone takes the time to solve your problem, you should reward them by accepting their answer.

Comment: @MaxPower could you please send me the link of similar question of mine (I mean similar case)

Comment: He means you asked something else "but you didn't ask with respect", quoting don Corleone. I (personally) don't care about arrows up and down, but seems like someone else do.

Comment: What's important is at least to confirm whether the solution is correct or flawed, just for the sake of the developers' community.

Comment: Peter you can see a link to all your previous questions by clicking on your name to go to your profile. I also agree with Oleg that it's important for future programmers who land on a page to be able to quickly see which answer solved your problem, if any did. But the great news is it's not too late! You can go through your previous questions today and click the check mark to accept each question that solved your problem. Usually your own comments there noting your problem was solved are there to remind you which answer solved your problem.

Comment: @OlegO yes my friend your answer was useful and solve my problem thank you and I really appreciate your help

Comment: @MaxPower Sorry my friend, I will try now to solve the problem. Sorry I didn't know how to do that or even I have to do that, so please accept my apologies

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping make Stack Overflow a better place Peter! And glad Oleg was able to solve your problem today too. Have a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not especially efficient, but given a list of parameters you can generate columns with a corresponding regex.

```
params = ['async', 'size']
for p in params:
    df[p] = df['long_string'].str.extract(fr'{p}=([^,]+)')
```